# Transferring ActiveX Textbox value to textbox powerpoint text boxes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to transfer the value a user has typed into an ActiveX Textbox to a standard label or textbox/boxes across the powerpoint.

The outcome I'm trying to have is that they place their name into the ActiveX textbox at the beginning. Then at the end they it will say congratulations with their name at the end.

This works for placing static text on the slide but how do I get it to take the value of the ActiveX textbox.

I realise it's simple thing just having a nightmare currently.

```
Sub tester()
With ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("Rectangle 5")
  .TextFrame.TextRange.text = "Your Text Here!"
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Sub MoveText()
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim OLEText As String
    
    Set oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox1")
    OLEText = oShape.OLEFormat.Object.Text
    ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("Rectangle 5").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = OLEText
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was pulling my hair out there! I can now edit and insert into the script. Legend.